# how to fix this issue on ie7 with menu and iphone?

Tags: html, css

So basically, please take a look at my website. If you have iphone you can take a look on it too, and try to move to the left or to the right, you will see the menu will move also, but it won't come back anymore.

Thats the first problem.

The second problem is that on ie7 the menu is right aligned. What could be the problem?

Also, on iPhone when you view page, the whole content is left aligned, not center - how to fix that?

The website is http://patiss-themes.com/test-site .

Also, I need menu to be "position: fixed;" , so it also comes down when I scroll down the page

If oyu can, please help me, since I will really appreciate that!

Comment: what is that black box at top left corner of page? If i removed position: fixed on your menu-wrapper div it got centered in ie7, but the black box got displayed over it...

Comment: Well, I need the position: fixed for it, since I need the menu to move down when scrolling page. About black box, don't know exactly what you mean. Did you check it on phone (if you have iphone) ? It's left aligned and the menu is bugged there too. When you zoom in and move to the right or left, the menu won't come back after moving back.

Comment: well i am using Opera on my iPhone and the menu is indeed left-aligned and buggy(page titles are outside white box), but it doesnt move at all :-)

Comment: I guess that black box is box shadow

Comment: maybe, but i see it left-aligned in IE so it looks like some black div, also there is some js error on page (object expected)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about the I-phone but you can get this working fine for IE-7.

there are two way of getting this actually in IE-7 your `#border-wrapper{ float:left;}` causing the issue for navigation section in IE7.

remove this and if you'll remove this some other layout  problems will also arise.

so you have to solve bunch of problems again

second way of getting this is : apply `margin-left` with `*` in your top-menu-wrapper

```
    #top-menu-wrapper
     {
          *margin-left:-960px /*For IE-7 only*/
     }
```